# Sorting is causing a problem with apostrophe

Tags: string, sorting, arraylist, collections, apostrophe

I have an ArrayList of Strings called arrayStr. I am using:

> Collections.sort(arrayStr)

to sort this ArrayList. However, I have one minor inconvenience when doing this.

Let's say there is a word called `Mary` in the ArrayList and there is another word called `Mary's`. The word `Mary's` will come before `Mary` when I sort the list, but I need it to come right after `Mary`.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: can you share your sorting function ?

Comment: The sorting function I used was the built in Collections.sort() method.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/collections-sort-java-examples/ suggests that `Mary's` cannot come after `Mary`

Comment: Sounds like you want a natural language order rather than lexicographical order. So you might try `Collections.sort(list, Collator.getInstance());`